# Is the a CLI way to download all photos from a Photos.app iCloud shared album?

Tags: mac, icloud, command-line, photos.app

Is there a way from the CLI on MacOS or Linux to download all the photos from a shared photo album (an album shared with me from another iCloud user, that shows up the shared tab on iOS or under the shared heading on MacOS) in Photos.app? I would like to setup a cron job to sync the photos locally so I can add them to the rest of our backuped data.

Comment: Quite broad in scope - when you say "album" what are you referring to?  iCloud?  Photos App?  Aperture?  When you say "download"  are you referring to a photo service (Flickr, Photobucket, etc.)?  **What exactly are you trying to accomplish?**

Comment: **shared photo album**: in iOS on the iPhone, in the Photos app, under the Shared tab (the one with cloud icon) albums shard from someone to me. In Photos.app on MacOS, these are listed under the Shared header in the sidebar.


**download**: I just want the photos on disk.

Comment: And iCloud and OneDrive don't do what you want?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with OneDrive. And iCloud doesn't do what I want, which is back up my data on my devices.

Comment: Well, it's this reason that this question is both way to broad and unclear as to what you are asking.  Consider revising so you clearly state what the issue is and what you have done thus far to address it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading all photos from iCloud Photo Library without Photos app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283630/downloading-all-photos-from-icloud-photo-library-without-photos-app)

Comment: Let’s leave this open but linked to the general case question -https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283630/downloading-all-photos-from-icloud-photo-library-without-photos-app some answers there could be CLI, but this needs to be CLI for cron/launchd scheduled tasks to run easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [iCloud Photos Downloader](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/icloud_photos_downloader) it is a command line interface for iCloud Photos based on Python.

To install, you can type `pip install icloudpd` should the requirement of Python 2.7.x or 3.6.x be met. If you use Python 2.6.x will fail.

If you require Python, I reccomend using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) Package Manager, which is known for being easy to install command line tools. If you’re going to install Python with this method, type `brew install python`

You can also install [Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-macosx10.9.pkg) using the package found on their website.

If you’re looking for more info about the package and command usages / 2 Factor Authentication scenarios, take a look at the [Repository’s Readme](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/icloud_photos_downloader/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Please include the relevant text from the link. Links expire all the time and can leave your answer useless..

Comment: It's a GitHub repo with a tool to download iCloud photos from the commandline. I can't copy the manual here, that would violate copyrights.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315308/313842 This is what I commented above. Thanks for the answer tho