# Backup Methods for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, windows

I have a iPhone 7 and I want to transfer all the images and videos to my laptop however I don't have an Apple Laptop only my windows laptop. I have tried using many methods but none worked well. Directly connecting the phone to my laptop and then manually copying files from the DCIM folder results in missing out most of the stuff. Importing also doesn't work as it seems to have copied files but is saved in some unknown location which I cannot find. I also downloaded the ICloud App for my laptop but it didn't help either.

I'm using IOS 13.6 on my iPhone and my Laptop runs on Windows 10 Home Edition.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I mis-read you had an Apple laptop instead of you do not, so you can’t use Image Capture to get them directly.

Comment: Are all of your photos/videos in iCloud? -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364036/9058

Comment: I am not sure if all are there some part of it is definitely there as i occasionally keep getting messages of space running out on iCloud @nohillside

Comment: Can you describe the current state of affairs a bit better in the question then, it's rather vague at the moment. If you tried iTunes and it didn't work, please add the error message you got to the question. If you assume your iCloud storage is full, please check and be specific. Maybe downloading the photos which *are* in iCloud and then deleting them so a second batch will get synced is an option. RIght now it's too much guesswork involved to understand the situation.

Comment: @nohillside I am not too familiar with the ecosystem so I'm facing these problems can you also guide me to some place where I can delete all my Cloud stored images and videos at once. I feel i am making some progress and this would be the last bit of my issues your last link in the comment has helped me a lot thanks

Comment: Deleting photos/videos from iCloud will also delete the same photos from your phone. Is this what you want? If yes, go to iCloud.com and delete there. Might be a bit cumbersome, but given your experiences with iCloud applications et al it's probably easiest to take a route which doesn't require additioal software.

Comment: @nohillside yeah i want to clean up the phone at large thanks a lot you've been very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install iTunes for this, see https://support.apple.com/HT210612 for details.

Comment: I have tried this at some point and it didn't work too well are there any other alternatives you might suggest

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab How many photos and do you care if they keep organization and metadata?

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab What exactly didn‘t go well?

Comment: There are close to 3000 Photos and videos and I don't really care unless it puts my data at jeopardy like gives them access to use my images freely @bmike

Comment: For some reason as I recall iTunes wouldn't work on iPhones which have data on ICloud and you need to use the ICloud app however the iCloud app doesn't give options to download everything at a go and to clean all the images in one go to free space

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab If you're using iTunes, check out this link: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201302#importpc followed by this one: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT210612 and make sure, as the first article mentions, to download any iCloud photos to your device so that they're stored locally. If you want an alternative to iTunes, use iMazing (https://imazing.com). In my opinion, it's millions of times better than iTunes.