# How to export iCloud Photos without a Mac?

Tags: icloud, photos

how can I export iCloud Photos without a Mac? Online on iCloud.com I can only export a .jpeg and not the original file including the Live Photo. On a Mac I could export it with the Photos app but I don’t have a Mac anymore.

EDIT: I only want to download a subset.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364036/

Comment: But I don’t want to download all but only a subset

Comment: Do you have a PC? If yes, log in to iCloud.com and download selected photos thus: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205323. Live Photos are only supported within the Apple ecosystem but you can download them as JPG + MOV.